# Processing XML With Hadoop Streaming failed

Tags: xml, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

i did

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.jar -inputreader "StreamXmlRecordReader, begin=<metaData>,end=</metaData>" -input /user/root/xmlpytext/metaData.xml -mapper /Users/amrita/desktop/hadoop/pythonpractise/mapperxml.py -file /Users/amrita/desktop/hadoop/pythonpractise/mapperxml.py -reducer /Users/amrita/desktop/hadoop/pythonpractise/reducerxml.py  -file /Users/amrita/desktop/hadoop/pythonpractise/mapperxml.py -output /user/root/xmlpytext-output1 -numReduceTasks 1
```

but it shows

```
13/03/22 09:38:48 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/03/22 09:38:49 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/Users/amrita/desktop/hadoop/temp/mapred/local]
13/03/22 09:38:49 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_201303220919_0001
13/03/22 09:38:49 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
13/03/22 09:38:49 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /private/var/root/hadoop-1.0.4/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=-kill job_201303220919_0001
13/03/22 09:38:49 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201303220919_0001
13/03/22 09:38:50 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
13/03/22 09:39:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 100%
13/03/22 09:39:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob: To kill this job, run:
13/03/22 09:39:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob: /private/var/root/hadoop-1.0.4/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=-kill job_201303220919_0001
13/03/22 09:39:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Tracking URL: http:///jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201303220919_0001
13/03/22 09:39:26 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201303220919_0001_m_000000
13/03/22 09:39:26 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
Streaming Command Failed!
```

when i went through jobdetails.jsp there it shows

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamInputFormat.getRecordReader(StreamInputFormat.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamInputFormat.getRecordReader(StreamInputFormat.java:74)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JobConf: missing required property: stream.recordreader.begin
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamXmlRecordReader.checkJobGet(StreamXmlRecordReader.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamXmlRecordReader.<init>(StreamXmlRecordReader.java:52)
    ... 13 more
```

my mapper

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import cStringIO
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
def cleanResult(element):
    result = None
    if element is not None:
        result = element.text
        result = result.strip()
    else:
        result = ""
    return result
def process(val):
    root = xml.fromstring(val)
    sceneID = cleanResult(root.find('sceneID'))
    cc = cleanResult(root.find('cloudCover'))
    returnval = ("%s,%s") % (sceneID,cc)
    return returnval.strip()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    buff = None
    intext = False
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.find("<metaData>") != -1:
            intext = True
            buff = cStringIO.StringIO()
             buff.write(line)
         elif line.find("</metaData>") != -1:
              intext = False
              buff.write(line)
              val = buff.getvalue()
              buff.close()
              buff = None
              print process(val)
        else:
            if intext:
                buff.write(line)
```

and reducer

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
     for line in sys.stdin:
         print line.strip()
```

can anyone tell me why this happens. 
I am using hadoop-1.0.4 im mac.
Is there any thing wrong. Should i change any thing .
pls help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the missing config variables as follows (add `stream.recordreader.` prefix and make sure they are the first arguments after the jar, enclosing them in double quotes):

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.jar \
  "-Dstream.recordreader.begin=<metaData>" \
  "-Dstream.recordreader.end=</metaData>" \
  -inputreader "StreamXmlRecordReader \
  -input /user/root/xmlpytext/metaData.xml \
  -mapper /Users/amrita/desktop/hadoop/pythonpractise/mapperxml.py \
  -file /Users/amrita/desktop/hadoop/pythonpractise/mapperxml.py \
  -reducer /Users/amrita/desktop/hadoop/pythonpractise/reducerxml.py \
  -file /Users/amrita/desktop/hadoop/pythonpractise/mapperxml.py \
  -output /user/root/xmlpytext-output1 \
  -numReduceTasks 1
```

Comment: yes i did previous error vanished but now showing "java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1"

Comment: Then i would say there is something wrong with your Mapper or reducer python - try and test sending a single line through from the command line

Answer (score 2):

Remove space in between comma and begin `, begin=<`.

The correct format is :

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar -inputreader
"StreamXmlRecord,begin=BEGIN_STRING,end=END_STRING" ..... (rest of the command)
```

This is due to the code surrounding the following lines in `org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob`

```
for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
    String[] nv = args[i].split("=", 2);
    String k = "stream.recordreader." + nv[0];
    String v = (nv.length > 1) ? nv[1] : "";
    jobConf_.set(k, v);
  }
```

Comment: Hiya, welcome to Stack Overflow! this is great that you've solved it. Can you please also add a (very brief) explanation of why the solution worked? I know for a typo that won't be much - but it's generally useful for any n00bs that stumble across this problem+solution and need to know why it was wrong. ;)